# Live Search Using Ajax and PHP mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I created a Live Search using AJAX,PHP and mysql.here when I click on search result ,redirecting me to a particular page  it works perfectly. Now I need a small change.
All I need is:
When I click on the search result, that particular result should be display in the input field.
Here is my AJAX code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

END OF AJAX CODE

PHP CODE

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("Base.php");
$dbase=new Base();

@$userID=$_SESSION['userID'];


$createdDate=date("Y-m-d");
$createdTime=date("h:i:s A");



 $partialStates=mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['q']);
$qryy="SELECT * from `gon_pro` WHERE `pro_name` LIKE
'%$partialStates%' ";
$pser=$dbase->execute($qryy);
$ser_nums=mysqli_num_rows($pser);
while($co[]=mysqli_fetch_array($pser)){
    }
?>



<?php
foreach ($co as $key => $namo) {
    $cv=$namo['pro_name'];
    $cv_id=$namo['id'];
    $cv_p=$namo['price'];
?>
<a  href="pro_det.php?prolod=<?php echo $cv_id; ?>"><p class="res
col-md-6"><?php echo $cv; ?></p></a>

<?php
}
?>
```

END OF PHP CODE

```
        function getStates(str) {

            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =""

            } else {

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
xmlhttp.responseText;

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "support/getStates.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: To answer we also need your HTML implementation. But basically you'l; need to attach an click-event listener to each result and process the clicked item to set an input's value.

Comment: <div class="col-md-10 " >
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-ss-8" >
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search"
class="pro_search"  onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" id="row"/>
                                <p id="results" class="" >
                                </p>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 padmin  col-xs-3 col-ss-3">
                                <button class="btn-search"><i
class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: here is the html side of the search.Thank you

Comment: For what it is worth, [this](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/c4f4285f9f159fc816f9) is how I would write your `getStates` function.

Comment: where is your ajax code? I suggest you should edit this question